# Keystroke Characters Repeatedly With AppleScript

Tags: automation, applescript, character

Is there a possible way to get an AppleScript to automate typing the following:

**aaaaaaaa**, then
**aaaaaaab**, then
**aaaaaaac**, all the way up to **zzzzzzzz**?

It's one of those simple functions but hard to figure out (for me, at least). :/

Comment: Do you mean all at once?  Multiple strings of specific length?  All on the same line?  One line for each string?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a permutation handler, but I'm not sure if you really want to run that set of permutations, you have seven char positions with 26 possibilities in each position, which gives a total of 7^26, or 9^21 different lines, which is a considerable set. However, you should be able to find a suitable handler here http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=30365&p=1

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nested repeat workflow that will accomplish what you want. It will run long time.

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    activate
    make new document
end tell

set ls to {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}

set theResult to {}

repeat with n1 from 1 to 26
    set c1 to item n1 of ls
    repeat with n2 from 1 to 26
        set c2 to item n2 of ls
        repeat with n3 from 1 to 26
            set c3 to item n3 of ls
            repeat with n4 from 1 to 26
                set c4 to item n4 of ls
                repeat with n5 from 1 to 26
                    set c5 to item n5 of ls
                    repeat with n6 from 1 to 26
                        set c6 to item n6 of ls
                        repeat with n7 from 1 to 26
                            set c7 to item n7 of ls
                            repeat with n8 from 1 to 26
                                set c8 to item n8 of ls
                                set r to (c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 & c6 & c7 & c8 as string)
                                -- can write each iteration somewhere:
                                keystrokeThis(r)
                                -- or, just save to a list variable all at once and then later process the list:
                                set theResult to theResult & r
                            end repeat
                        end repeat
                    end repeat
                end repeat
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end repeat
end repeat

-- you now have all your strings in theResult as a list and can do things with it as a whole

on keystrokeThis(s)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "TextEdit"
            keystroke s & return
        end tell
    end tell
end keystrokeThis
```